# How do I install a live ISO on an SD card so it boots anywhere?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot-loader, sd-card, bootable

How do I **install** (NOT live-persistence) an xNIX live-iso onto an sd card? I want it to be able to boot on most machines.

---

In depth:
I've burned a pendrive with parrotsec 4.4 64 bit to install parrot onto the 64GB SD card I have, while having my system drives unplugged (as to not flash EPS onto the existing recovery partition). This failed miserably, even after trying different flashing tools - Etcher which is recommended by Parrot, YUMI, Rufus & UNetbootin - in different modes (auto, DD, ISO) provided by the tools, while also using different partition setups each time (RAW, or pre-formatted FAT32/EXT4) and mixing up MBR/GPT tables with each setup.

Well, it failed booting the sd card pretty much every time with different results: fallback to grub shell, UEFI shell or just a cursor blinking. I think this is ESP/GRUB's fault to some degree, because I'm guessing it wasn't able to find the relevant *.efi and I didn't really know how to point it to where it needed (sdx/EFI/boot/*.efi?)

Comment: Also, from my past experience trying to install live OSes on pendrives - or any flash memory that's not an SSD for that matter, its a total PITA, that's the reason I was asking for help in the first place. GRUB goes nuts trying to find the bootloader, UEFI booting is always quirky and BIOS booting works but that's after exhausting me, fiddling with CSM, USB-KEY booting and such.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for the behavior of some of our users here. I don't care if you're new, that doesn't make your questions unwelcome here. And there's nothing in your question indicating that you're playing with things you don't understand. Some of the comments you received were way out of line. That said, your question really is too broad. Could you edit and actually ask a single, specific question?

Comment: @terdon thank you for your input. I've revised my question (again), feel free to edit it as you see fit, or ask for any more detail if needed... P.S. I'm not new here as I've said, this is just a way of avoiding the toxic atmosphere regarding specific OSes around here.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that you are confusing "install <OS> on <device>" with "burn <ISO> on <device>". In this scenario, you should have at least 2 devices: one where you burn the ISO and another where you install the OS. You can't install an OS on the same device where the ISO resides in, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, that seems much better. As for the toxicity, despite what you just went through here, there are actually cases where questions about such OSs are well received here. What we don't like is people who think that pentesting distros are also good choices for watching YouTube or whatever. But yes, I do understand what you mean and it's something we need to work on.

Comment: @nxnev I've used usb A already fitted with parrot 4.4 (as in live-usb) to try and install onto usb B. Note that I never used the gtk installer if that even changes anything significantly, which I doubt.

Comment: @psecshark, 1. Do you want to make a live drive with Parrot? 2. Or do you want to install Parrot from a live drive to an SD card (installed like into an internal drive, but into an SD card)? -- I have done both many times (but not with Parrot), and I can try to help you, but I must know what you want.

Comment: @psecshark, Another question: Which version of Parrot are you trying? You can specify the name of the iso file.

Comment: @psecshark, I will download the 64-bit 'security' iso file and try to install it. Please notice the size - Please check that the card/pendrive for the live system is big enough for the iso file (some 4 GB drives are actually 3.7 GiB or smaller). And you will need a fairly big SD card for an installed system, I would guess at least 16 GB. -- It will take some time until I can answer ...

Comment: @sudodus I've added the relevant info to the question to remove clutter from the comment section. Also, did you manage to install parrotsec onto a pendrive or sd card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

- **Cloning works well in order to create a live Parrot Security 4.4 64-bit drive. I think that it is a good idea to run Parrot live or persistent live from an external drive (USB pendrive, SD card ...).** The drive must be big enough (at least 4 GB).
- It is difficult but possible to install Parrot into an SD card (at least 16 GB).
- The graphical installer, that is available via the live system fails for me too as described in the question.
- Things will be cleaner and easier, if you [can] disconnect your internal drives, and use only the drives involved in this task.

### How to install to an external drive (in this case an SD card)

- Boot into the live Parrot drive
- In BIOS mode you get a syslinux menu. Select 'Live' at the top of the menu to get a graphical desktop environment
- **Insert the SD card** (I did it via a USB adapter).
- Open a terminal window and run a few commands to prepare the SD card.

  ```
  sudo lsblk -fm
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=1
  sudo -H gparted /dev/sdX
  ```
- The `lsblk` command will help you identify the target drive, the SD card
- The `dd` command will wipe the first mibibyte, which makes the installer more willing to install grub. It is ***very important*** to write to the SD card, which means that you must select the correct drive letter (for example `a` or `b` replacing `X`) for the SD card. Otherwise you may destroy important data in some other drive. Things are safer, if you have disconnected all other drives (except the live drive and the SD card).
- In `gparted` you can 'see' the drive information. There should be no partition, not even a partition table.

  - create a new MSDOS partition table (via 'Device')
- Shutdown
- Remove the SD card

---

- Boot from the Parrot live drive again
- In BIOS mode you get a syslinux menu. Select 'Install' near the bottom of the menu. It will bring you to a text mode installer, the old 'debian installer'.
- **Insert the SD card** (I did it via a USB adapter).
- Select 'Standard Installer' in the next small menu.
- Select language ... (I will not describe all the steps here).
- Select 'Guided - use entire disk'
- Select the device pointing to the SD card ...
- Install the GRUB boot loader, answer 'Yes'
- Select the device pointing to the SD card
- Finish the installation
- Remove the Parrot live drive
- Let the computer reboot

---

### Run the installed Parrot from the SD card

- Reboot and you should be able to boot into your installed Parrot :-)

### Fix to improve portability

Let us assume that the computer boots nicely at reboot, with the same drives connected as when you created the Parrot system in the SD card (for example no internal drive connected).

- There may still be problems when you change which drives are connected (for example that you connect an internal drive). The same problems may occur, when you connect the SD card to another computer with one or more internal drives connected.
- These problems may be solved by changing the `linux` line in the menuentries for Parrot in the file `grub.cfg`, that is used.

  Boot from another drive, for example a live drive.

  ```
  sudo lsblk -f             # identify the drive and check the UUID
  sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt  # mount the drive that contains grub.cfg
  sudo nano /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg  # edit grub.cfg
  ```

  Look for the `menuentry` paragraphs for Parrot and each line that begins with `linux`. Replace the `root=/dev/sda1` or similar with a device specification to

  ```
  root=UUID=042cf088-b051-4961-b206-2c223a31dee2
  ```

  where the string `042cf088-b051-4961-b206-2c223a31dee2` should be replaced with the actual UUID string (probably present in the `menuentry`, and identified by the `lsblk` command line.

I edited this in my Toshiba laptop with the SD card connected via a USB adapter as `/dev/sda` and no internal drive connected. I tested it in the same Toshiba with an internal drive and in my Intel NUC with two other drives connected. The following screenshot is from the Intel NUC and shows that the SD card is connected via the built-in slot as `/dev/mmcblk0` and there are two other drives connected. Please notice `root=UUID=...` in `grub.cfg`

[image]

### Comments

- In most computers you can boot into SD cards via USB. Some USB adapters work with some computers, but there is no guarantee, several computers and adapters do not cooperate during the boot process.
- In some computers you can boot into SD cards via PCI (typical for built in SD slots in laptops). This is not very common, so you should not expect it to work for you.
- Please notice that the lifetime of an SD card with an installed system can be rather short due to wear because of writing many times to the same memory cells. Cloned live drives are read-only, and not affected at all. Persistent live drives live longer, because there are fewer write operations.

### Some commands

Some commands in a terminal window of my installed Parrot test system,

```
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Parrot
Description:    Parrot 4.4
Release:    4.4
Codename:   stable
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $sudo lsblk -fm

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for tester: 
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT  SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda                                                                 29.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1 btrfs        79ad87de-08a8-4623-9afc-7c8b25daa228 /          25.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2                                                                 1K root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda5 swap         dcf02e42-29de-4baa-adc9-febf55e611f8 [SWAP]      3.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0                                                                 1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  6.1M  378M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        26G   12G   14G  47% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           384M   24K  384M   1% /run/user/1000
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3831         502        2611          56         718        3048
Swap:          3977           0        3977
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $uname -a
Linux parrot 4.18.0-parrot10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2parrot10 (2018-11-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
┌─[tester@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $
```

Comment: I prayed this would work, unfortunately it didn't. This time all I'm getting is a black screen (no shell at all) - even tried CSM legacy and UEFI modes, but got the same results. I have a custom bootdump USB from work which pointed out no drives were found although I replugged my own drives (which are set up for dual-booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) after finishing the installation. -- removing the USB adapter enabled booting as usual -- What do you think about installing in a vm? Should I give it a go?

Comment: **Alternative A** is to: 1. Create a Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (64-bit) boot drive and an 8 GiB partition in the SD card; 2. Install Parrot into the free space outside those 8 GiB (and let it fail with the bootloader); 3. Install Lubuntu into the 8 GiB partition. It should find Parrot and make a menuentry for it (in Lubuntu's grub menu); 4. Reboot and you should be able to boot into Parrot.

Comment: **Alternative B** is to use Parrot **live** (or if you can make it, **persistent live**). I think this is how many people use it.

Comment: **Alternative C** is installing Parrot in a **virtual machine**. I am not sure if it will be able to do everything that it can do, when booted directly into the computer hardware. Maybe.

Comment: I'm actually using it persistent on my work laptop almost daily, while I have another pen drive running live when I'm on a client's machine. I wanted to install it onto the SD so I can benchmark if I would get any more performance out of it. Also, the plan was to either tune ext4 for the SD to avoid excessive writes or convert to f2fs which is optimized for flash anyway.

Comment: Second, I want to thank you for the time you put into this, I appreciate you very much for your effort! -- Anyhow, I'm going to try the method you suggested with Lubuntu to see if it works. I'm optimistic, but If it won't, isn't there any other way? Like... edit the boot listing (using another live usb) or maybe check if the UUID its pointing to is correct? -- I have a feeling parrotsec is being a bitch trying to mount itself onto sda again, even though the disk order changes when I replug my drives.

Comment: @psecshark, I could make it work in my test computer, a Toshiba laptop with InsydeH2O UEFI/BIOS system and Intel i5 generation 3 CPU. I tested only in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) because it is easier. First I succeeded via Lubuntu, then after wiping the SD card I could make it work directly with Parrot security. -- If you want good performance (not only testing security issues), I suggest that you install another linux distro (for example Lubuntu), that is easier to manage.

Comment: @psecshark, In general, the following link can help you install an Ubuntu or Debian [based] system into an external drive, [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Comment: @psecshark, I added a paragraph to the answer with a **fix to improve portability**. It works for me. Please check if it will help you.

Comment: Hey, so I tried the process again, this time using virtualbox (with EFI ticked on) to install onto the sd with the same steps except I added the EFI folder myself (from another bootable live-usb) after the install and made sure the UUID would be correct. Glad to say it boots on most machines in my household, so I can't wait to try this out at my work environment! -- Thank you so much, words can't express how much I'm grateful!

Comment: You are welcome @psecshark :-)

Comment: Update: this blazing fast microsd card now fitted with an install of ParrotSec has been a godsend. I actually feel the difference in speed mostly when generating my logs or moving big files around, but also in regular use, which is something I didn't expect. -- Thanks again! @sudodus